# How to show html code on button in Android and style it

Tags: android

I want to put `html` codes on buttons as text in my android application and style them.

**For ex:** I want to create a help button and put `"&#x2754;"` as text to it.

Below is the code I have written in the activity.

```
Button btHelp=((Button) findViewById(R.id.btHelp));
btHelp.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#x2754;"));
```

But if I want to change the color of it. I tried by giving span and font in the above statement but it is not applying.

Can you please let me know how to give the colors for this. Also let me know if there is any better way to do so.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `btHelp.setTextColor`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text color, simply use:

```
btnHelp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

or

```
btnHelp.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
btnHelp.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

But that won't work with emojis like your `White Question Mark Ornament`. If you want to change that question mark color, you will have to make a drawable file with button drawables (png) that have that question mark with the color you want. You can do that from photoshop or any other program.

Comment: This character is an emoji. It's a White Question Mark Ornament. You can't change its color. What you can change is text's color itself.

Comment: I thought there is other text in your button. If you want to change that question mark color, you will have to make a drawable file with button drawables (png) that have that question mark with the color you want.

Comment: Hi Hussein, you are correct. setTextColor won't work that I already tried. But when I try this character in html file, I could able to change its color.

Comment: I am not expert in html, but languages differ. Html recognizes the emojis in another way different from java. So that's not possible in java. You will have to create a drawable for that. If you need help, tell me.